# Integrate react-intl with react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-intl

I am using `react-intl` for translations throughout my app. I am now trying to use a translated message as Header of a table using `react-table` in the following way:

```
    {
    Header: <FormattedMessage id="users.user" defaultMessage="User" />,
    accessor: 'role',
},
```

But I get the following errror message:

```
×
```

Error: A column ID (or string accessor) is required!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `intl.formatMessage` API instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just Add
id element to the object like this:

```
{
 Header: <FormattedMessage id="users.user" defaultMessage="User" />,
 id:'h1', //<--------------
accessor: 'role',
},
```